# Are there direct usefull applications of the quantum Fourier transform not requiring heavy other subroutine

Tags: quantum-algorithms

I know that the quantum Fourier transform has many applications such as order finding (which is used in Shor algorithm), phase estimation, etc.

However those algorithms require extra subroutines which are often much "heavier" in term of gates and qubits required.

My question is:

Are there applications of the quantum Fourier transform in which the typical number of gates required (decomposed on Clifford+T) is about the same that there are in the quantum Fourier transform itself.

If so, for which size of the quantum Fourier transform can we expect a quantum advantage compared to today supercomputers.